# Change link colour anomaly

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, colors

I've changed the link colour on my website to black but the link for "SHOP" won't change colour.

The website is http://stalagmitesband.com.

HTML:

```
<nav class="nav-primary">
      <div>
        <ul id="menu-links">
          <li id="about-link"><a href="#about-anchor">ABOUT</a></li>
          <li id="listen-link"><a href="#listen-anchor">LISTEN</a></li>
          <li id="watch-link"><a href="#watch-anchor">WATCH</a></li>
          <li id="gigs-link"><a href="#gigs-anchor">GIGS</a></li>
          <li id="shop-link"><a href="https://stalagmites.bandcamp.com/merch" target="_blank">SHOP</a></li>
          <li id="projects-link"><a href="#projects-anchor">OTHER PROJECTS</a></li>
          <li id="contact-link"><a href="#contact-anchor">CONTACT</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
```

CSS:

```
a:link {
   text-decoration: none;
   font-family: 'josefin sans', quicksand,'Open Sans', sans-serif;
   font-size: 15px;
   font-weight: 400;
   color: black;
}

a:link:hover {
   text-shadow: -2px 2px 2px rgba(180,160,0,0.5);
   color: black;
}
```

Any help would be brilliant.

Cheers

Comment: You have a:visited set to red this might be the issue?

Comment: Try this `a{color:black}` and `a:hover{color:black}`

Comment: I can't see the problem: http://i.stack.imgur.com/6FZDi.png

Comment: Thanks for responding guys. It's fixed now. Take it easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that when you have visited the link it has an additional pseudo tag.
This should fix it.

```
a:visited {
   color: black;
}
```